# How do I form the URL to call this WebAPI function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have this controller in an MVC 5 WebAPI application and I can't seem to figure out how to form the URL to call it. I keep getting a 404. tried .../ssa, /ssa/ssamedians, /ssa/ssamedians?titles=abc... What am I missing?

```
public class ssaController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult getSsaMedians(string Titles = "")
    {
        SsaDB db = new SsaDB();
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Title_Medians> medians = db.getTitleMedians(Titles, null, null);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return Ok(medians);
        }
        catch
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

There are also Actions called getSsaMediansByAaa() and getSsaMediansByBbb(). Once I got rid of the api/ in the routeTemplate, I now get a "Multiple actions were found that match the request".

Comment: I would expect `/api/ssa/ssamedians` to work if you didn't change `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` in `WebApiConfig.cs`

Comment: I notice you're returning a NotFound() exception.  Is the code in the action being hit at all? It's not something as simple as the code in the try failing? As a NotFound() returns a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your **WebApiConfig.cs** file and add this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "SSATitles",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{Titles}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ssa", action = "getSsaMedians", Titles = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

For more information on webapi routing look here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 1):

You have an parameter in your method, that means that you need to add an extra link in your url.

Examlple.com/DirToApi/getSsaMedians/YourString

You may also want to check your RouteConfig file in your App_Start